# GoogleSignIn on iOS : iTunes Connect error RFC1738

Tags: ios, arrays, google-signin

I've got an app that uses GoogleSign (via cocoapods).
The URL schemes added in the info.plist are array types (automatically generated as it seems). If I keep them that way, I can't upload my app on ITC (error RFC1730 Url schemes must begin with an alphabetic character). The url scheme shown is an array indeed [182385...googleuser.content.com]

If I edit the info.plist and remove the array, my app can be submitted to the appStore, but it crashes under GGLContext configureWithError: as it needs an array.

How can I solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you confirm that the URL schemes don't accidentally begin with whitespace (such as a carriage return)? I'm pretty sure that happened to me once when I copied and pasted...

Comment: no, it starts with a number :-/ I simply edited the info.plist xml file and removed the <arrays></arrays> tags :(

Comment: It shouldn't start with a number, you need the client ID reversed as Todd has shown below (e.g. make it start with com.). You don't need it right way round at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you might have the wrong URL scheme entered -- the whole "URL schemes being an array" thing is a bit of a red herring.

The trick is that you need to have two URL schemes added to your app:

1. Your bundle ID
2. Your client ID *in reverse*

That means your second URL scheme should look something like:

com.googleusercontent.apps.4815162342-lasq48paoryp8asfh3498tyalk

and not:

4815162342-lasq48paoryp8asfh3498tyalk.apps.googleusercontent.com

It seems like maybe you're using the second version, which begins with a number, and perhaps that's what's throwing off iTunes Connect.

Comment: Weird... I delete this entry since I already had the reverse url, and it worked... Really weird. Anyway, thanks for your answer :)